# Filter records using Linq on an Enum type

Tags: linq, enums

I'm hoping this is a simple solution. I have a field (PressType) in a table (Stocks) that is seed populated by using an Enum. The table stores the data as an integer. However when I want to query some data via Linq it gives me issues. I can filter any other fields in the table using this format however on the Enum populated field it says

> the "==" operator cannot be applied to operands of type "Models.PressType" and "string".

Any help you could give would be appreciated, thanks.

```
var test = db.Stocks.Where(x => x.PressType == myValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Linq. Your problem is that `myValue` is of type `string`. You need to convert your string to the enum first.

```
string myValue = SomeControl.Text;
Models.PressType myValueAsEnum = (Models.PressType)
              Enum.Parse(typeof(Models.PressType), myValue);
IQueryable<Stock> test = db.Stocks.Where(x => x.PressType == myValueAsEnum);
```